# what is a good mouse/keyboard macro recorder?

Tags: paid-applications

Robotux looks perfect but appears to be no longer available. I tried to download it based on a 3 year old askubuntu post but there is no way that I can see to pay the $2.99 in the app store. I've looked at gnee but it's way too complicated vs similar tools that run in windows. there just doesn't seem to be a comparable tool for Ubuntu 15.xx. or is there? thanks in advance!

p.s. I am able to use a Windows macro recorder Teamviewered into my Ubuntu box but this is very inelegant... I would rather employ a Linux based solution...

Comment: xdotool can execute key command (click move etc) but not record and playback...?